# MS Office upgrade

Tags: office365

My system has MS Office 2003. If we install 2016 in that, will the existing  Office files will be upgraded from 2003 to 2016 automatically.

Please clarify on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing office files won't be upgraded. The old files will be readable, printable and editable by the new office suite. After editing you can decide whether to save them in the old format (.DOC; .XLS) or the new format (.DOCX; .XLSX). Once saved in the new format it is not always certain you can go back to the old format. This depends on what new features you used. New format files cannot be processed by the old MS office suite.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.... Is this same applicable for MS access file.

Comment: Advise: google more often. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Word-2013-to-open-documents-created-in-earlier-versions-of-Word-609bbdba-96f2-407b-baaf-d8e53d60d34f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0):

MS Office 2003. files that's in your system will  not be upgraded in to new offices 2016 file format. but as you know you can open, read , and edit your old file by new office 2016

on hare i want to tell you if you have office  2016 files in your system and you want to open them  by office 2003 then it will not open.

and after upgrade your office suite then you have need to open your old file and save them again by the same name but new extension